# Can I trigger soundcloud widget to play from and event outside of the player?

Tags: javascript, events, soundcloud

I would like to use a soundcloud widget but before playing have a custom css "player" and hide the container holding the widget until the user clicks play on the css player which will hide the faux player and show the soundcloud player. This would be done by adding and removing a class on click using javascript. 
Is there a way to programmatically trigger soundcloud play button using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. On the [SoundCloud Embed/Widget Info Page](https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed), you can open developer tools on the big play button of the example widget - and you'll see the class of that play button:

[image]

Simply programmatically click it!

```
$(".playButton__play").click();
```

Note: The SoundCloud widget may change over time, in which this solution may not work anymore due to their changes, in which you can attempt to do this solution again. However, a more robust solution would be to use their Web API for generally more control.